# acts_as_commentable validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, acts-as-commentable

I recently started back up with Rails and things are going well up until
now.

I've set up acts_as_commentable in my Post model and it's working great.
Problem is users are able to create a "blank" comment. I've added the
following validations in the comment.rb file generated by
acts_as_commentable to limit the comment length:

```
validates_length_of :comment, :minimum => 3, :too_short => "must be at
least {{count}} words.", :tokenizer => lambda {|str| str.scan(/\w+/) }

validates_length_of :comment, :maximum => 200, :too_long => "must be
shorter than {{count}} words. Make sure there are no links or
elements.", :tokenizer => lambda {|str| str.scan(/\w+/) }
```

The show view form for the comment is the following:

```
<%- form_for [@post, @comment] do |f|-%>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <%= f.text_area :comment, :rows => 3 -%>
  <p><%= f.submit -%></p>
<%- end -%>
```

However I am getting the following error only when validation fails (if
a normal length comment is created the site works):

```
Template is missing

Missing template comments/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder,
:rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths
"/...", "/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/devise-1.2.1/app/views"
```

Any idea how I can render just a regular validation error? Thanks in
advance!

**UPDATE**

CommentsController as requested:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @post
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:return_to] ||= request.referer

    if current_user.admin?
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    else
      @comment = current_user.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    @comment.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to session[:return_to] }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end

end
```

Development Log:

```
Started POST "/posts/1/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-18 15:20:05 -0400
  Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"P5x6xSS6VgxPg58Ubftc4FcUQKZFQbpKOKO9zFeE7cM=", "comment"=>{"comment"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "post_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.3ms)   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

  Post Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed   in 154ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template comments/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/.../app/views", "/.../vendor/plugins/dynamic_form/app/views", "/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/devise-1.2.1/app/views"):


Rendered /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
```

Comment: can you show your controller?

Comment: Added the comments controller. Hope it helps!

Comment: is {{count}} is working? can you check development.log for more details. The error you getting because the object is not being save and the action and rails look for create template to render. also, try to use %d in place of {{count}}.

Comment: Not sure if {{count}} is working. I just replaced the validations with "validates_presence_of :comment" for now to keep things simple and I'm still getting the same error. I also edited my post to include the log file output of the error. Any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: DOH! I just realized that since I don't have a valid return when a comment fails on the create action in CommentsController it obviously couldn't render the template. Still need to find a way to show the validation errors but a big step forward. Thanks Nash and Naren!

Comment: It's very easy. You can find it in `@comment.errors` And you really should read about validation here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks Nash! What I'm stuck with is rendering the validation error on the comment form on my posts show view. I think that's a bit different from what you are proposing. Any idea how to display those errors? I will definitely look into learning Rails more thoroughly - in fact I just purchased "Agile Web Development with Rails Fourth Edition" to actually learn rather than hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happening because you haven't defined yet what controller should do if validation fails.

Try this:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.user_id = current_user.id
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
  else # validation fails
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: That's exactly what it was Kleber! I stumbled on it a bit ago. What I'm stuck with is rendering the validation error on the comment form on my posts show view. Any idea how to display those errors? Sorry for the additional question!

Comment: render 'posts/show' does show the error! However, now the post comments aren't loading. Maybe I need a break haha. FYI my posts/show controller has the following: @post = Post.find(params[:id]) @comments = @post.comments @comment = @post.comments.new #Where @comment is the user form comment

Comment: Just looked in the log. Maybe this has something to do with it?: "Started POST "/posts/1/comments" for 127.0.0.1"  - not sure why it's adding the /comments...

Comment: maybe you will have to fetch the comments on the create method, before rendering the posts/show

Comment: Kleber, you are the man! That did it :-)   Is there any specific book, articles or class that you had to learn Ruby/Rails? As per my comments above I purchased "Agile Web Development with Rails Fourth Edition" and should receive it soon but would appreciate any other sources that might help. Thanks for all the great help!

Comment: No man, just practicing a little on my free time as a hobby, but I always reading articles, tutorials on the net and of course, helping other people here, like you, helps me to learn too!